# f:ajax doesn't update component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a select and I want that when the user doesn't select anything it prints an error. So I use validator and my xhtml code is:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="students"
                        value="#{studentsBean.selectedStudent}"
                        converter="studentsConverter" effect="fold">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{studentsBean.studentsList}"
                            var="student" itemValue="#{student}"
                            itemLabel="#{student.name}" />
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="students"  process="@this" />
                        <f:validator validatorId="studentNotNull" />
                        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="studentPanel"/>

                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:panelGroup id="studentPane">
                        <h:message for="students" style="color:red" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is that if I don't select anythin it print me "The students is not selected" while I choice an student the label it doesn't disappear.

the validatior works and I don't think I must write the code.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="students"
   value="#{studentsBean.selectedStudent}"
   converter="studentsConverter" effect="fold"
   required="true" requiredMessage="Student is required">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." noSelectionOption="true"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{studentsBean.studentsList}"
       var="student" 
       itemValue="#{student}"
       itemLabel="#{student.name}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Add  in your form

```
 <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" life="3000"/>
```

and of course, update `msgs` in form submit